# WPF DataGrid copy all headers (rows & columns)?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, clipboard

Trying to programmatically copy the entire content (row and column headers included) of a WPF DataGrid to clipboard when user double-clicks it. Copying column headers and cell data is straightforward. However, row headers are not copied. My code generates row headers "on the go", as rows are loaded, and maybe this is the problem. I am leaning towards storing row headers in a collection when the DataGrid is populated. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?